# ¿Por qué no me guarda la información en mi base de datos?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente en el código no me actualizan los datos pero tampoco sale error

```
   ----------------------------------------------------  
   require_once "../../clases/categorias.php"; 
    $data = array("idcategoriadat" => $_POST['idcategoria'],
    "nombrcategoria" => $_POST['nombrcate']
    );
    $catego = new Categorias();
    echo Categorias::actualizarcategoria($data);
    -----------------------------------------------------       
    public function actualizarcategoria($data){
        //print_r($data);
        $conexion = Conectar::conexion();
        $sql = "UPDATE t_categorias  SET nombre = ':nombre' WHERE idt_categorias = ':idt_categorias'";
        $query = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        //print_r($query);
        $query->bindParam(":nombre", $data['nombrcategoria']);
        $query->bindParam(":idt_categorias", $data['idcategoriadat']);
        
        // JAJAJ el nombre de la tabla
        $abc=$query->execute();
        //echo $abc;
        return $abc;
        $query->close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error en tu código es que estás usando comillas simples para los marcadores de `:nombre` en tu instrucción SQL:

```
$sql = "UPDATE t_categorias  SET nombre = ':nombre' WHERE idt_categorias = ':idt_categorias'";
```

Si revisas los ejemplos del [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php), verás que no se usan comillas simples, los marcadores sirven para indicar que ahí va un dato que se pasará más adelante. Una consulta preparada en ese sentido no es como una consulta tradicional donde podrías entre comillas simples los datos de tipo VARCHAR o TEXT.

Otra cosa, cuando uses funciones, lo último que debes poner es el `return`, pues todo lo que haya después de él no se ejecutará, porque la función vuelve a donde fue llamada al encontrar el `return`.

Prueba de este modo, debería funcionar, salvo otros errores:

```
public function actualizarcategoria($data){
    //print_r($data);
    $conexion = Conectar::conexion();
    $sql = "UPDATE t_categorias  SET nombre = :nombre WHERE idt_categorias = :idt_categorias";
    $query = $conexion->prepare($sql);
    //print_r($query);
    $query->bindParam(":nombre", $data['nombrcategoria']);
    $query->bindParam(":idt_categorias", $data['idcategoriadat']);
    
    // JAJAJ el nombre de la tabla
    $abc=$query->execute();
    //echo $abc;
    $query->close();
    return $abc;
}
```

Convendría que controles la cantidad de filas afectadas, para verificar que realmente ocurrió una actualización. Por ejemplo, un `UPDATE` podría fallar si viola alguna restricción, o la cantidad de filas puede ser `0` si se manda a actualizar con datos idénticos a los ya existentes.

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado.